# cv::line function is drawing lines inverted

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using opencv 2.4.7. It seems that cv::line function is drawing the lines inverted.
For example if the function is called to draw the line betwwen  (10,54)  and (82,54) the output is attached

Is it a bug or the general x,y axis convention is inverted in opencv ?

Comment: I usually see that difference between OpenGL functions and MFC functions. One use left-top as origin and other system something else. so something similar you have to see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

cv::Mat uses (y,x) order to access elements (Matrix convention), but cv::Point and all methods using it (like drawing methods) are (x,y) order (image convention).

So if you want to draw from (x=10,y=54) to (x=82,y=54) you would write

`cv::line(image, cv::Point(10,54),cv::Point(82,54),...);`

In addition: openCV image origin is `top-left`, y going down and x going right.

Comment: Thank you. just another query. Is your argument true for all member function of Mat ?

Comment: I am not sure whether ALL member functions go that way, but the general `.at<type>(row,column)` uses the matrix convention (row first which would be y in an image), while `cv::Point p(x,y)` accesses a Mat in image convention. So `mat.at<type>(y,x)` accesses the same matrix-element/pixel as `mat.at<type>(cv::Point(x,y))`